# Unary minus vs 2's complement to make number negative

Tags: bitwise-operators, unary-operator

I was just reading about [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) method and was wondering if it is faster than using unary minus to make number negative.

> Unary Minus

```
int a=10;
a=-a;
```

> 2's complement

```
int a=10;
a=~a+1;
```

> OUTPUT

`-10` in both cases
Which would take less time?

Comment: Asking "which would be more faster" about such trivialities may not be off-topic, but isn't well received here.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I wanted to know which uses less time to make number negative? Or do they take same time?

Comment: It would be *very* weird if a compiler would generate faster code for the second one.

Comment: Have you tried to benchmark both options to find out?

Comment: The answer to these types of questions is almost always "benchmark it yourself on your platform" because it depends on your compiler, your flags and your system. In this case, the answer is that the 2nd approach isn't guaranteed to be equivalent. The use of 2's complement is not mandatory.

Answer (score 4):

Second option is not defined behavior. C++ standard does not mandate 2's complement for representation of negative numbers, it is not guaranteed that it would do what you expect to do.

On platforms using 2's complement, speed of both operations would be the same, since compilers will optimize both forms to whatever is faster.